# What is the change in ratio of histone to protamine in men with infertility called?

Tags: reproduction, literature

I am neither a biology researcher nor a student. In a paper (written by a biology researcher) I am translating into English, there is the following statement which, according to the text, must have a name and I fail to find the English name:

> It is showed that in men with infertility histone to protamine ratio changes and the change is called ...

What is the change called? I guess it's something unnatural/abnormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is termed "abnormal packing".

Source: "*Sperm Chromatin: Biological and Clinical Applications in Male Infertility and Assisted Reproduction*" by Armand Zini & Ashok Agarwal (2011), p 172.